# Socket.IO: How to emit an event to all (authenticated) users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, jwt

Here's the server code:

```
io.set('authorization', socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: jwtSecret,
  handshake: true
}));

app.post('/login', function (req, res) 
{
  if((req.body.username === "test") && (req.body.password === "test"))
  {
    var token = jwt.sign({ username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password}, jwtSecret, { expiresInMinutes: 60*24*7 });

    res.json({ token: token });
    console.log(req.body.username + " logged in");
  }
  else
  {
    res.status(401).send('Wrong user or password');
  }
});

io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
  // test event
  socket.on('ping', function (data) 
  {
    io.emit("pong", data)
  });
});
```

And here the client:

```
var server = $("#server-input").val();
var obj = { username: $("#login-input").val(), password: $("#password-input").val() };

$.post(server + "/login", obj)
.done( function(response)
{
  connect_socket(response.token);
});

function connect_socket(token)
{
  socket = io(server, {query: 'token=' + token});

  socket.on("connect", function() 
  { 
    socket.emit("ping", {hi:"there"});

    socket.on("pong", function(data) 
    {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Now, when one user connects, the ping gets send and is received. When the same user connects a second time, the pong will be received on both instances, but when another user connects the pong will only be reveiced by that user. User a and b don't see eachother.

How can I fix this? Could this be a problem with the authentication?

Comment: I don't see any code that does authentication here, so it's hard to see how you can be asking about a problem with authentication?

Comment: Added the relevant parts.

Comment: Can you describe what you're expecting to happen with user A and user B.  A webSocket connection connects a client to a server - period.  If you want a message sent to more than one client from your server, then your server has to explicitly send it to more than one client, either using chat rooms or broadcast or by actually looping through more than one socket to send a message to each.

Comment: `io.emit()` is supposed to be a broadcast

Comment: I don't see any problem here. As for each user you are passing (client) username and password, from code it looks like it is been authenticated. hence the new user connect. As socket is open and once user is authenticated then only it will receive events. To verify one way is pass wrong user/password and run the client and see what happens.